# Extracting the date from an HTML element using R

Tags: html, r

I'm trying to see if I can extract dates from an online community using R. At the moment, I'm a bit of a newcomer, but not having much luck using the R package. It seems to pull a huge list rather than any specific date or time.

I've tried using the Rvest package to read URL and then select the HTML element I want to extract the date. I just can't find the date anywhere within it.

This is what I've tried so far.

```
  discussion <- read_html("https://en.community.sonos.com/wireless-speakers-228992/bass-cutting-out-on-play-5-will-come-back-intermittently-when-volume-is-turned-up-5568948")
  local.date <- discussion %>% 
  html_nodes(".qa-latest-post-time") %>% html_text()
  discussion
```

Is there a better way?

Ideally I'd get a specific date (and time) from this. If not, at least a specific date would be useful.

Comment: I do not perfectly know this package, but maybe regex would save you. `grep` is one of my favorite functions to extract anything. And as dates have a very strict format, regex would match your expectations

Comment: @ElieKerArno Regular expressions break down in a spectacular fashion when trying to parse structured markup such as HTML. They’re the wrong tool for the job. You could hack something together but the result would be inefficient, unreadable and incredibly brittle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You’re selecting the nodes’ text but the date information is stored in an *attribute* (you can find this out by printing the HTML nodes themselves):

```
discussion %>% html_nodes('.qa-latest-post-time') %>% html_attr('datetime')
```

> Ideally I'd get a specific date (and time) from this.

The site’s source code does not seem to contain post times — at least not in your example.

Comment: You're a genius, thank you. Is there a list of html_attr I can call somewhere? I'm still learning how rvest package works and trying to get to grips with what arguments I can pass into html_attr

Comment: @RichardMillington Did you look at the documentation? `?html_attr`. You can also list all attributes instead of just one by using `html_attrs`. In general the documentation of packages such as rvest is quite good, and they contain introductory tutorials (“vignettes”). In this case, to be found at https://rvest.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Thanks, I did look at the documentation but I think as a newcomer I don't quite grasp the full extent of what it means. 

For example, I don't know how you knew the data was stored at an attribute or how you knew that 'datetime' would work. If datetime works, what else works here? :-) I know these are really beginner concepts, I'm just struggling with them a little.